# I want to increase the number of articles in the slider

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I need some help in adding more articles to the Slider. Knowing that the number currently 3 articles. I needed to increase the number to 5 articles.

and this code in file slider.blade

```
<section class="mainslider commonslider">
<div id="imgslider" class="owl-carousel">
    @foreach($sliderNews as $sn)
    <div class="item">
        <div class="sliderimg" style="background-image:url({{asset($sn->image)}});"></div>
        <div class="slidertexts">
            <div class="container">
                <span ><a href="{{route('cat.news',$sn->category->slug)}}" alt="{{$sn->category->name}}" style="color: white">{{$sn->category->name}}</a></span>
                <h1>{{$sn->title}}</h1>
                <p>{!! str_limit( strip_tags($sn->article_html),100,'...') !!} </p>
                <a href="{{route('article',$sn->slug)}}" class="viewbtn">شاهد</a>
            </div>//
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Comment: I dont know Laravel or your code, but I can see what I would try to achieve this, so why cant you give something a try and then if that fails ask a question

Comment: So wrong on so many levels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think from your controller you need to write a query and limit it to 5

```
$data['posts']=DB::table('posts')->limit(5)->get();
```

you can as well write an admin script to control the increment and decrement of the number of articles to be displayed any time.

Answer (score 0):

Just changing this line

```
@foreach($articles->take(20)->random(3) as $sButtom)
```

To

```
@foreach($articles->take(20)->random(5) as $sButtom)
```

Comment: its not work bro its make the Buttom under the slider 5 like the photo  https://imgur.com/q4uoRTT